# Custom Password Character in TextBox

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a `TextBox` containing a password that I want to be able to show or hide depending on the value of a `CheckBox`. I am able to hide the characters by setting the `UseSystemPasswordChar` property in the `CheckChanged` event on `chkBox`:

```
private void chkBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (chkBox.Checked)
    {
        txtBox.UseSystemPasswordChar = false;
    }
    else
    {
        txtBox.UseSystemPasswordChar = true;
    }

}
```

I would like to use a custom character to replace the password text instead of the system character. How can I use a custom password character?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess what you want can be done with:

```
 txtBox.PasswordChar = '$';
```

or more specifically

```
txtBox.PasswordChar = chkBox.Checked ? Char.MinValue : '$';
```

Comment: Thanks! This is working once i check the box. Initially I am able to see the characters that I enter into the textbox. How this can be corrected?

Comment: Run the same code in `Form_Load`, or call `chkBox_CheckedChanged(null, null)` from `Form_Load`

Comment: @Nate, If you're using the WinForms designer, it's more idiomatic to simply set a value for `PasswordChar` in the properties window of the designer rather than in `Form_Load`.

Comment: @Jason, Thanks. It is working. But on unchecking the box the entered text is not coming back. Here is the code: private void chkBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (chkBox.Checked)
    {
        txtBox.PasswordChar= '$';
    }}

Answer (score 0):

```
textBox1.PasswordChar = '$';
```

This code is ignored if property "UseSystemPasswordChar = true", change it to "false" and it will work.

Comment: ,Thanks.It did work after setting the property to false.